# How can I wait in a repeat loop in Roblox Lua

Tags: lua, wait, repeat, roblox

```
game.Workspace.PetRooms.FireRoom.FireRoom.Floor.Touched:Connect(function(hit)
local player = game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(hit.parent)
local char = hit.Parent -- Character
local hum = char:FindFirstChild("Humanoid") -- Humanoid
if hum then -- If humanoid then...
    if hum.Health ~= 0 and player.Team == game.Teams.Scientists then -- Makes sure that character is not dead; makes sure that character is a scientist
        repeat
            wait (10)
            hum.Health = hum.Health - 10 -- Kills the character slowly
        until hum.Health == 0
    end
    player.Team = game.Teams.Infected -- Changes the player's team to infected AFTER they die
end
end)
```

The "wait(10)" is supposed to wait 10 second in between every "- 10" health but the code just waits 10 seconds and then kills the player quickly.

Comment: with how many health points does the player start?

Comment: With 100 health points

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have this callback connected to the `Touched` event, and the event will fire every time a player touches the part. If the player is walking across the floor, it will fire every time the player's foot hits it.

What is probably happening is that this event is firing multiple times, and you have a bunch of these repeat-while loops all running at the same time, causing the player's health to drop very quickly.

I would recommend debouncing the connection so that only one loop happens per player :

```
-- create a map of players touching the floor
local playersTouching = {}

local floor = game.Workspace.PetRooms.FireRoom.FireRoom.Floor
floor.Touched:Connect(function(hit)
    -- check that the thing that hit is a player
    local char = hit.Parent -- Character
    local hum = char:FindFirstChild("Humanoid") -- Humanoid
    if hum == nil then
        return
    end

    -- escape if this player is already touching the floor
    local playerName = char.Name
    if playersTouching[playerName] then
        return
    end

    -- the player was not touching before, so flip the debounce flag
    -- everything after this point happens once
    playerTouching[playerName] = true

    -- check if character is not dead and a scientist
    local player = game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(hit.parent)
    local isScientist = player.Team == game.Teams.Scientists
    local isAlive = hum.Health > 0
    if isScientist and isAlive then
        -- start a loop to kill the player
        while hum.Health > 0 then
            wait(10)
            hum.Health = hum.Health - 10
        end

        -- Change the player's team to infected
        player.Team = game.Teams.Infected
    end

    -- clear the debounce flag
    playerTouching[playerName] = false
end)
```

Answer (score 0):

i can't really think of anything besides [GetPropertyChangedSignal](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/function/Instance/GetPropertyChangedSignal)
try that maybe

Comment: Do you know why the script doesn't wait(10) between all the -10 health and instead just does the -10 health really fast after waiting 10 seconds? I don't understand.